# create and retrieve sortable options list with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginator

I'd like to  and retrieve sortable options list with KnpPaginatorBundle but I failed.
This is the form:

```
       <form action="" method="get" class="form_sort" id="myForm">
           <span class="manage_title">Sort by:</span>
                <select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="option" onChange="sendForm();">
                     <option value="">-------</option>
        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country A-Z', 'country', {'sort': 'country', 'direction': 'asc'}) }}
        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country Z-Z', 'country', {'sort': 'country', 'direction': 'desc'}) }}
                 </select>
       </form>
```

And this is the view in KnpPaginatorBundle\Pagination\sortable_option.html.twig

```
<option {% for attr, value in options %} {{ attr }}="{{ value }}"{% endfor %}>{{ title }}</option>
```

and this is the action:

```
    public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {

        $option = $request->query->get('option'); //get query option
        list($directiuon, $sort) = explode(":", $option);

        $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend($sort, $direction);

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $listTravels,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', $page)/*page number*/,
            5/*limit per page*/
        );

        return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
            'pagination' => $pagination
        ));
    }

    $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->findAll();

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $listTravels,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', $page)/*page number*/,
        5/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ));
}
```

I'd like to know how to create the options correctly in the form with **sort=country and direction=asc** and the second option with **sort=country and direction=desc** , also I'd like to retrieve those parameters in the controller after **POST** and correct mistakes in the Action (near explode).

Right now when I select the first choice for example I get this url:

```
http://localhost/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?option=Country+A-Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are sending the form, I wrote you a piece of JS in your previous question which:

- Gets the value of the selected option in eg. localhost/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?sort=country&direction=desc
- Redirect to the page you retrieved from the value.

I think it might also not work because KNPPaginator default template is a link, so instead of href = "KNP_LINK" need to value = "KNP_LINK". Modify the file

```
KnpPaginatorBundle \ Pagination \ sortable_option.html.twig
```

Comment: yes I use `sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_option.html.twig` now and I created `KnpPaginatorBundle \ Pagination \ sortable_option.html.twig` this part is fine. But the js code doesn't work :/

Comment: Can You show me (pastebin) generated html DOM of select?

Comment: what is that html DOM ?

Comment: Paste me form html source.

Comment: `<select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="option" onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option  translationCount="" sort="country" direction="asc" class="sortable" href="/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?sort=country&amp;direction=asc" title="Country A-Z">Country A-Z</option>
            <option  translationCount="" sort="country" direction="desc" class="sortable" href="/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?sort=country&amp;direction=desc" title="Country Z-A">Country Z-A</option>
</select>
`

Comment: Try replace sortable_option.html.twig to this:
`<option {% for attr, value in options %} {% if attr == 'href' %}value{% else % }{{ attr }}{% endif %}="{{ value }}"{% endfor %}>{{ title }}</option>`

Comment: `<select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="option" onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option  translationCount="" sort="country" direction="asc" class="sortable" value="/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?sort=country&amp;direction=asc" title="Country A-Z">Country A-Z</option>
<option  translationCount="" sort="country" direction="desc" class="sortable" value="/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?sort=country&amp;direction=desc" title="Country Z-A">Country Z-A</option>`
</select>

Comment: Generated html looks now good, so try this JS:
http://pastebin.com/KHSc2r8N

PS. delete onChange="..." atribute in Yout select now.

Comment: yes thank you very much, it works now and I get this url `http://localhost/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?sort=country&direction=desc`

But another question please, how can I get those parameters sort and direction in the controller ? `$option = $request->query->get('option'); //get query option`

Comment: Start using this bundle to pagination, and records will be sorted automatically :) [Usage example](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#controller)

Comment: But how it works automatically ?! I'm using a query in Repository and I should pass it those two parameters in `->orderBy('t.'.$sort, $direction);` Isn't ?

Comment: `public function getListTravelsFrontend()
 {
  
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
   ->leftJoin('t.image', 'i')
   ->addSelect('i')
   ->leftJoin('t.agence', 'a')
   ->addSelect('a')
   ->Where('t.enabled = 1')
   ->orderBy('t.'.$sort, $direction);
   
   return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

 }`

Comment: `if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET')
  {
   $direction = $request->query->get('direction'); //get query option
   $sort =  $request->query->get('sort');
   
   $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend($sort, $direction);
   
   $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
             $listTravels,
              $this->get('request')->query->get('page', $page)/*page number*/,
             5/*limit per page*/
           );
  
         return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
    'pagination' => $pagination
   ));
  }`

Comment: I found that solution